# Show that $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose that $f$ has an isolated singularity at $0$ and satisfies $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$ in some punctured neighborhood of $0$. Show that $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$.

I tried defining a function $g =f(z)\sqrt{|z|}$. From here we can see that $$0 \leq |g(z)|=|f(z)\sqrt{|z|}|\leq |f(z)|z|| \leq |\sqrt{|z|}| $$ and by squeeze theorem it is clear that $g(z)$ would go to $0$ and by Riemann $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$. Since $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$ so does $f$ and we are done, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Presumably, $f$ is analytic. Otherwise, $f=\sqrt{1/|z|}$ is an immediate counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) to $f(z)\sqrt{|z|}$ because that function is not holomorphic in a punctured neighbourhood of $0$.

But you can apply the theorem to $f$ directly: $\lim_{z \to 0} z f(z) = 0$ implies that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: Gotcha I see, that makes sense I totally overcomplicated it !